# pandas read_excel doesn't read all rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with "pandas read_excel", thats my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('myExcelfile.xlsx', 'Table1', engine='openpyxl', header=1)
print(df.__len__())
```

If I run this code in Pycharm on Windows PC I got the right length of the dataframe, which is 28757
but if I run this code on my linux server I got only 26645 as output.

Any ideas whats the reason for that?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify you have an Excel File with 28,757 columns? Microsoft states the limit for the number of columns is 16,384. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: It will be difficult to help you without knowing what the data looks like. Can you give an extract? Also, `len(df)` gives you the number of rows, not columns

Comment: Sorry, big mistake, if have 28,757 rows not columns.

Comment: The Data are simple Strings, no spaces, no empty rows or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.
The problem was an empty first row in my .xlsx File.

My file is automatically created by another program, so I used openpyxl to delete the first row and make a new .xlsx File.

```
import openpyxl

path = 'myExcelFile.xlsx'
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet = book['Tabelle1']
#start at row 0, length 1 row:
sheet.delete_rows(0,1)
#save in new file:
book.save('myExcelFile_new.xlsx')
```

**Attention, in this code sample I don`t check if the first row is empty!
So I delete the first line no matter if there is content in it or not.**

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
import pandas as pd

data= pd.read_excel('Advertising.xlsx')

data.head()
```